# Can I get a the RouteTemplate from AspNetCore FilterContext?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

In AspNetCore, given a FilterContext, I'm looking to get a route template e.g.
`{controller}/{action}/{id?}`

In Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi I could get the route template from:
`HttpControllerContext.RouteData.Route.RouteTemplate`

In System.Web.Mvc I could get this from:
`ControllerContext.RouteData.Route as RouteBase`

In AspNetCore there is:
`FilterContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template`

However, not all routes are attribute routes.

Based on inspection if the attribute is not available, default routes and/or mapped routes can be assembled from:
`FilterContext.RouteData.Routers.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase>().First()`
but I'm looking for a documented or a simply better approach.

Answer (score 6):

**Update (24 Jan 2021)** 
There is a much much simpler way of retrieving the `RoutePattern` directly via the `HttpContext`.

```cs
    FilterContext filterContext;
    var endpoint = filterContext.HttpContext.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint;
    var template = endpoint?.RoutePattern?.RawText;
    if (template is null)
        throw new Exception("No route template found, that's absurd");
    Console.WriteLine(template);
```

`GetEndpoint()` is an extension method provided in `EndpointHttpContextExtensions` class inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace

#### Old Answer (Too much work)

All the route builders for an ASP.NET Core app (at least for 3.1) are exposed and registered via `IEndpointRouteBuilder`, but unfortunately, this is not registered with the DI container, so you can't acquire it directly.The only places where I have seen this interface being exposed, are in the middlewares.
So you can build a collection or dictionary out of one of those middlewares, and then use that for your purposes. 
**e.g**

#### Program.cs

*Extension class to build your endpoint collection / dictionary*

```cs
    internal static class IEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions
    {
        internal static void BuildMap(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
            foreach (var item in endpoints.DataSources)
                foreach (RouteEndpoint endpoint in item.Endpoints)
                {
                    /* This is needed for controllers with overloaded actions
                     * Use the RoutePattern.Parameters here 
                     * to generate a unique display name for the route 
                     * instead of this list hack 
                     */
                    
                    if (Program.RouteTemplateMap.TryGetValue(endpoint.DisplayName, out var overloadedRoutes))
                        overloadedRoutes.Add(endpoint.RoutePattern.RawText);
                    else
                        Program.RouteTemplateMap.Add(endpoint.DisplayName, new List<string>() { endpoint.RoutePattern.RawText });
                }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        internal static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> RouteTemplateMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        /* Rest of things */
    }
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            /* all other middlewares */
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                //Use this at the last middlware exposing IEndpointRouteBuilder so that all the routes are built by this point
                endpoints.BuildMap();
            });
        }
```

And then you can use that Dictionary or Collection, to retrieve the Route Template from the FilterContext.

```cs
    FilterContext filterContext;
    Program.RouteTemplateMap.TryGetValue(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName, out var template);
    if (template is null)
        throw new Exception("No route template found, that's absurd");

    /* Use the ActionDescriptor.Parameters here 
     * to figure out which overloaded action was called exactly */
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', template));
```

To tackle the case of overloaded actions, a list of strings is used for route template (instead of just a string in the Dictionary) 
You can use the `ActionDescriptor.Parameters` in conjunction with `RoutePattern.Parameters` to generate a unique display name for that route.

Comment: On a second glance, looking at the updated answer (24-Jan-21), it looks similar to the OP's own answer. @Daniel, Can you expand on why that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

These are the assembled versions, but still looking for a better answer.

### AspNetCore 2.0

```
    FilterContext context;

    string routeTemplate = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template;

    if (routeTemplate == null) 
    {
        // manually mapped routes or default routes
        // todo is there a better way, not 100% sure that this is correct either
        // https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/1b0258ab8fccff1306e350fd036d05c3110bbc8e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Template/TemplatePart.cs
        IEnumerable<string> segments = context.RouteData.Routers.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase>()
            .FirstOrDefault()?.ParsedTemplate.Segments.Select(s => string.Join(string.Empty, s.Parts
                .Select(p => p.IsParameter ? $"{{{(p.IsCatchAll ? "*" : string.Empty)}{p.Name}{(p.IsOptional ? "?" : string.Empty)}}}" : p.Text)));

        if (segments != null)
        {
            routeTemplate = string.Join("/", segments);
        }
    }
```

### AspNetCore 3.0 with Endpoint Routing

```
            RoutePattern routePattern = null;

            var endpointFeature = context.HttpContext.Features[typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature)]
                                           as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature;
            var endpoint = endpointFeature?.Endpoint;

            if (endpoint != null)
            {
                routePattern = (endpoint as RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern;
            }

            string formatRoutePart(RoutePatternPart part)
            {
                if (part.IsParameter)
                {
                    RoutePatternParameterPart p = (RoutePatternParameterPart)part;
                    return $"{{{(p.IsCatchAll ? "*" : string.Empty)}{p.Name}{(p.IsSeparator ? " ? " : string.Empty)}}}";
                }
                else if (part.IsLiteral)
                {
                    RoutePatternLiteralPart p = (RoutePatternLiteralPart)part;
                    return p.Content;
                }
                else if(part.IsSeparator)
                {
                    RoutePatternSeparatorPart p = (RoutePatternSeparatorPart)part;
                    return p.Content;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown Route PatterPart");
                }
            }

            if (routePattern != null)
            {
                // https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/1b0258ab8fccff1306e350fd036d05c3110bbc8e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Template/TemplatePart.cs
                routeString = string.Join("/", routePattern.PathSegments.SelectMany(s => s.Parts).Select(p => formatRoutePart(p)));
            }
```